# Java not recognizing elements in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a program where I make an arraylist to hold some cab objects. I keep getting an error that what I get from the message is that java does not recognize that the arraylist has objects in it. This is the error that I am getting.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 20, Size: 20
>       at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
>       at edu.Tridenttech.MartiC.app.CabOrginazer.main(CabOrginazer.java:48)

This is the code that i am trying to get to work

```
public class CabOrginazer {

private static List<CabProperties> cabs = new ArrayList<CabProperties>();
private static  int count = 0;
private static boolean found = false;


public void cabOrginazer() 
{

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CabRecordReaper reaper = new CabRecordReaper("C:/CabRecords/September.txt");
    CabProperties cabNum;

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cabNum = new CabProperties();
        cabs.add(cabNum);
    }
    while(reaper.hasMoreRecords())
    {
            CabRecord file = reaper.getNextRecord();
            for(int j = 0; j < cabs.size(); j++)
            {
                if(cabs.get(j).getCabID() == file.getCabId())
                {
                    found = true;
                    cabs.get(j).setTypeAndValue(file.getType(), file.getValue(), file.getPerGallonCost());
                    cabs.get(j).setDate(file.getDateString());
                    break;
                }

            }

            if(found == false)
            {
                cabs.get(count).setCabId(file.getCabId());
                count++;
            }
            /*for(CabProperties taxi : cabs)
            {
                if(taxi.getCabID() == file.getCabId())
                {
                    found = true;
                    taxi.setTypeAndValue(file.getType(), file.getValue(), file.getPerGallonCost());
                    taxi.setDate(file.getDateString());
                    break;
                }


            }*/

    }


    for(CabProperties taxi : cabs)
    {
        System.out.print("cab ID: " + taxi.getCabID());
        System.out.print("\tGross earning: " +  taxi.getGrossEarn());
        System.out.print("\tTotal Gas Cost: " + taxi.getGasCost());
        System.out.print("\tTotal Service Cost: " +  taxi.getServiceCost());
        System.out.println();

    }


}

}
```

**line 48** is the inside of that if statement where it says `cabs.get(count).setCabId(file.getCabId());` 
with the little knowledge I have of Java. Java should know that there are elements inside of `cabs` and I should be able to set that `id` of the cab. What can cause Java not to recognize that the arraylist is populated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The list *isn't* populated with an element at item `count`. Look at the exception: you've got 20 elements in the list, so the valid indexes are 0 to 19 inclusive. You're asking for record 20 (i.e. the 21st record). That doesn't exist.

It sounds like your block should be something like:

```
if (!found)
{
    CabProperties properties = new CabProperties();
    properties.setCabId(file.getCabId());
    // Probably set more stuff
    cabs.add(properties);
}
```

You may well be able to get rid of the `count` variable entirely - and your initial population of the list with dummy properties. It's very odd to populate a list like that to start with - that's typically something you do with an *array* which has a fixed size. One of the main benefits of using a `List` such as `ArrayList` is that it's dynamically sized.

Answer (score 4):

Java is recognizing the members just fine. You have 20 members in the array, indexed from index 0 through index 19.

You are asking for index 20, which does not exist.

The loop for:

```
while(reaper.hasMoreRecords())
```

must be running many more times than you expect, and your data is hitting the `found == false` if condition (which you can just say `if (!found) { ...` ) many times, and on the 21st time it fails with the index-out-of-bounds exception.

You should figure out how to use your debugger too.